# f(2) not defined in this piecewise function

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Find all points of discontinuity:

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x+2,  & \text{if $x > 2$} \\[2ex]
x^2, & \text{if $x < 2$}
\end{cases}$$

I currently am not sure at all if my workings of this problem is correct but this is what i got:
**the lim exists and it is 4** BUT what i dont know is if $f(2)$ exists as it is not defined if $x = 2$ etc
SO... my conclusion is: ***f(x) is discontinuous at x = 2***

please correct me if i am wrong, because i am uncertain about my interpretation, thanks!.

Comment: If your definition of continuity is that $\lim_{x\to 2^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 2^-} f(x) = f(2)$, then $f$ is not defined at 2, hence it cannot be continuous at 2.  As an aside, it is incorrect to say that "$f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=2$."  $f(x)$ is the value of $f$ at $x$.  It is an element of the range of $f$---in this case, a real number.  It is more correct to say that $f$ is discontinuous at 2.

Comment: Correct! $2\notin D_f$

Comment: @Flakemistake Almost. The word "discontinuous" doesn't belong there. It should be "undefined" or "ill-defined", or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Domain of $f$ is a disconnected set,$(-\infty,2)\cup(2,\infty)$ in $\Re$. Also f is continuous in each of these intervals as mentioned in the 'comments'. We can not talk of f being continous or discontinous at 2 as $2\notin D_f$.